# Netplan configuration is not persistent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, netplan

I have configured my network interfaces in my `Ubuntu bionic (18.04)` server using `netplan`, and afterwords I ran `netplan apply` and the configuration kicked in.
In particular, I configured the DNS servers, and my server did resolved ips with the nameservers I configured in my `netplan` configuration.

But, after reboot, the configuration didn't last and any resolving was by default to the `127.0.0.53` nameserver. Only after running `netplan apply` the configuration kicked in again.

How can I make the `netplan` configuration persistent to reboots?

Output of `cat /etc/*-release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: What sort of server do you have?

Comment: It's a virtual server, running on vsphere @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 1):

Typically once netplan configurations are written to /etc/netplan these will be persistent over reboots. Although I have seen issues where the `netplan apply` doesnt complete as expected when the interface is active. I have found adding `--debug` to the apply to be useful to see what is really happening

`sudo netplan --debug apply`